# How to get NSError from NSError**?

Tags: objective-c

I have an error variable of type `NSError**`, and I want to get the `error.description` field of the error. Is there a way to cast it to NSError?

Comment: `NSError **` is typically used as a param by methods for supplying a pointer to an `NSError *` which then gets populated by the error object (to overcome single value returns). So in a nutshell: `NSError *error = nil;` then pass `&error` and after the call, get the `error.description`. [NSHipster has a great article on this](https://nshipster.com/nserror/)

Comment: Add some code please.

Comment: `error[0].description`

Comment: And how do you initialise `error`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `NSError **` is a pointer to a `NSError *`. To access the underlying `NSError *`, dereference it with `*`. However, this is only legal if the indirect pointer is not NULL.

```
if (error != NULL) {
    NSString *desc = [*error description];
    ...
}
```

To make this a bit more concrete:

```
NSError **error = NULL; // Pointer to NULL
[*error description];   // Invalid and will crash.

NSError *underlyingError = nil;
[underlyingError description];      // This is fine and just returns nil
NSError **error = &underlyingError; // Pointer to a pointer
[*error description];               // This is fine and just returns nil
```